# What is the meaning of the @ symbol in a :let command

Tags: vim

[The Vim docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#last-pattern) provide this command to clear the last search. Is one supposed to type `@/` or `/`. I'm assuming the former, but it gives wonky results. If it is the latter, what's the purpose of `@`

```
:let @/ = ""
```

Answer (score 2):

You are meant to type it exactly like in the example you provided.  To see why you need to look at the following help section:

```
:help :let-register
```

To summarize, ":let" can set variables of various types, but it can also modify options by prefixing the name with `&`, e.g.:

```
:let &tabstop=4
```

And it can set registers, by prefixing the register letter with an `@`, as in your example.